# Drupal's attach behaviours : react on all newly loaded content?

Tags: 7, javascript

I've got two different modules which in many ways work together. One of the things they work together on is that module A loads content via AJAX, and module B needs to attach event listeners to the content loaded.

However, it appears that when content is loaded via AJAX by module A, only the 'attach' function of **Drupal.behaviours.a** gets invoked, and not the 'attach' function of **Drupal.behaviours.b**. Both functions gets invoked on page load, but not on subsequent AJAX content loading.

```
// This runs every time module A loads new content.
Drupal.behaviors.a = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    alert('a:attach');
  }
}

// This only runs on page load, but never when module A loads new content.
Drupal.behaviors.b = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    alert('b:attach');
  }
}
```

How do i make the 'attach' function of **Drupal.behaviours.b** run every time any module loads new content?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Drupal.attachBehaviors();` to the ajax success callback?

Comment: No, but should that not be taken care of automatically? I thought that was the whole idea of the 'attach' function; that it should be called on page load and page update? It does seem, however, that only the 'attach' function for the invoking module gets called on page update though?

Comment: That was my understanding yes, I haven't ever looked into it too deeply though. I know there's been times when after an AJAX call I've needed to reattach behaviours so I just assumed it was required

Comment: Looking at drupal.js :

"Drupal.attachBehaviors is added below to the jQuery ready event and so runs on initial page load. Developers implementing AHAH/Ajax in their solutions should also call this function after new page content has been loaded, feeding in an element to be processed, in order to attach all behaviors to the new content."

It does seem that I need to invoke the attachBehaviours myself. But; it puzzles me that module A's 'attach' function runs even though I haven't invoked attachBehaviours in the AJAX success callback...?  Why just for the invoking module, and not all modules?

Comment: That puzzled me too a bit, it's hard to say without seeing the code in that module's attach function though

Comment: If you want a catch-all solution `$('body').ajaxSuccess(Drupal.attachBehaviors);` will probably work

Comment: Well, the code in module A's 'attach' function does not really do anything but add a couple of listeners on various elements. There is nothing to indicate that Drupal.attachBehaviours() should be invoked for that module's 'attach' function. However, could it be that the AJAX functionality in Drupal somehow automatically invokes the 'attach' function for the module responsible for the AJAX? Could it be that Drupal somehow keeps track of which module set up which event listener?

Comment: I believe i found the reason. Module B's JavaScript was not quite right. It started out with (function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.b = { attach: [...] }})(jQuery); After having fixed it to simply Drupal.behaviours.a { attach : [...] }; things worked better. @Clive : you're welcome to post one of your comments, I'll accept it as an answer since you did after all contribute to the discussion which again lead to me looking further into details.

Answer (score 4):

This, from the comments in `misc/drupal.js`, explains how it's supposed to work:

- Drupal.attachBehaviors is added below to the jQuery ready event and so
- runs on initial page load. Developers implementing AHAH/Ajax in their
- solutions should also call this function after new page content has been
- loaded, feeding in an element to be processed, in order to attach all
- behaviors to the new content.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in Drupal.behavior.b:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors($(this));
```